# How to import/use Gramps records to produce family history book?

Tags: family-tree, gramps, books

In the past, I've used PAF and Gramps to manage my family's genealogy records. I really like Gramps in particular, because of its flexibility and ability to store pictures, stories, etc. I am currently interested in turning this information into a family history book that I can give to various family members as a gift. In particular, this book would have things like family records and trees, pictures, personal stories and journal entries, and LDS temple records. I would really like to not have to copy/retype all of this information currently stored in Gramps into a word document if I don't have to. Is there a good program (preferably free or open source), or even some type of plugin for Gramps that can help me create this book from the data stored in Gramps' database? I do have experience with programming and scripting, but I'd rather avoid writing a program to parse through this information if I don't have to.

Comment: Both posts are very helpful! Thanks for the links. I will take a look at these options and see what will work best, but it looks like I will have to do some python/latex to get it just the way I want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the Gramps website here is the relevant section for using the [Book Reports](http://www.gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php?title=Gramps_3.4_Wiki_Manual_-_Reports-_part_3) which allow you to create a single document (i.e. a Book) containing a collection of graphical and textual reports.

Also see what looks like a great example of someone creating a [401 page family book](https://www.joachim-breitner.de/blog/archives/492-401-page-family-book-published.html) in [gramps by Joachim Breitner](http://gramps.1791082.n4.nabble.com/401-page-family-book-built-using-gramps-td3594560.html)

You might also want to try asking this question on one of the [Gramps mailing list](http://www.gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php?title=Contact#Mailing_lists) with your programming experience probably the gramps-devel list.

Comment: Good find, great looking book.

Answer (score 2):

I have used **The Complete Genealogy Reporter** available [from here](http://www.tcgr.bufton.org/tcgrover.htm) in the past for sending details to relatives. There is a free 30 day trial so you can try it out.

I also tried **Ancestral Author** [from here](http://www.ancestralauthor.com/) and that is quite good too. The trial version watermarks your reports.

Neither is particularly expensive and may give you what you need.

If they aren't 100% of what you want as they produce a pdf file you can get one of the free pdf to word converters to give you a document that you could then edit in your word processor.